# Invalid category Exception is thrown when I try to loadproductcollection from a magento cron job?

Tags: category, cron, product-collection

I am creating a Cron job to do some operations in the product collection and I have defined a block for my job. I have extended my block from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List. But the block is not getting converted to html, its failing in the beforeHtml call. When trying to load the product collection. And by tracing back I have found that the exception thrown is category invalid.

The template is loaded for an email, using block inside the email template.

Block - **availableproducts.php**

```
class Test_Module_Block_Availableproducts extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{

    public function getAvailableProducts()
    {

    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        //return parent::_getProductCollection();
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }
}
```

Block Init from Email template

```
{{block type="test_module/availableproducts" area="frontend"  category_id="4" template="email/availableproducts.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Blocks should not be used in crons. And please post your code.

Comment: So what will I do if I want to dynamic content in an email which need to be scheduled ?

Comment: If I do a Mage::init from the cron job observer, The block is getting converted to HTML without issue.. But facing some other issues in the product url access. Is using Mage::init is a right/valid way ?

Comment: To get the right URLs you should specify a storeId, using `Mage::setCurrentStore($storeId)`

Comment: When I call setCurrentStore it directly calls destroy.